# JS filter multiselect array only returns last elem

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am building a historical dash (currently with fake data due to security) and I have the multi select list that gens the first name of the person in alphabetic order. Now when selecting one name it regens the table with said name. When I select multiple names, it regens the table with the "lowest" alphabetical name. I cant figure out why my filter function is not building the new array with all selected names that are true in the "selected" statement. However I used the push() function and that works but only shows the first name. Any help would be awesome, I am new to JS and working with DOM is really fun!

histData is the main array with all info,

fNameArr is the re populated array from the filter method given the multi selections

Here is my js:

```
function mSelList(){

    var selName = document.getElementById("jomax");
    var fNameArr;

    for(i=0; i<selName.length;i++){

         let currentName = selName[i];

         if(currentName.selected == true){

             let fName = currentName.value;

             fNameArr = histData.filter(function(data){

                 return data.first_name == fName; 

             });

         }
 }

 function createTable(){

         var col = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < fNameArr.length; i++) {
             for (var key in fNameArr[i]) {
                 if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                     col.push(key);
                 }
             }
         }

         // create table section with css filters
         var table = document.createElement("table");
         table.setAttribute("class", "table is-hoverable is-bordered is-narrow");
         table.setAttribute("id", "table");

         var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                  

         for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
             var th = document.createElement("th");
             th.setAttribute("class", "is-uppercase is-size-7");  // attributes
             th.innerHTML = col[i];
             tr.appendChild(th);
         } 

         for (var i = 0; i < fNameArr.length; i++) {

             tr = table.insertRow(-1);

             for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                 var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                 tabCell.innerHTML = fNameArr[i][col[j]];
             }
         }
         var tblSec = document.getElementById("tableSec");
         tblSec.innerHTML = "";
         tblSec.appendChild(table);
         }
         createTable();

     }
```

Comment: The `mSelList ` is missing a `}`

Comment: possible issue: your line `var selName = document.getElementById("jomax");` later assues that `selName` is an array. `document.getElementById` will always return a dom element. Maybe try to grab all the elements by their classname using `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @gaganshera the closing bracket is after the createTable() function

Comment: @SpencerMay the "jomax" ID is from a select attribute in the HTML, under select attribute are the "options", a select attribute in html is technically an array in itself, so the select[i] is just looping through all the names to see which ones are selected

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementById` and running a loop over it? `getElementById` will return one specific element not a list of element. Here is [mdn_link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more info.

`var selName = document.getElementById("jomax");`

I would suggest to use class instead.

Comment: I would agree however when I use the "push" function to create the array it returns the element as the full array, when using the "filter" function is where it only returned the array with a single element